# Anchor "button" not working when put in "row" class

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Web beginner here.  I'm trying to use a Bootstrap carousel with multi-items in one slide.  The carousel uses the "row" class to put three items in a slide.  The anchor for the first item works, but the anchor "buttons" don't work on the second and third item.  They're not even clickable.  If I take out the `<div class="row">`, the buttons are now clickable, but the items will be put in one column.  How can I fix this?  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the html for one slide.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <a href="{{rtn[0]['url']}}">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{rtn[0]['urlToImage']}}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:348px; height:233px; overflow:hidden; object-fit:cover;">
              </a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" style="height:116px;">{{rtn[0]['title']}}</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{rtn[0]['url']}}">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <a href="{{rtn[1]['url']}}">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{rtn[1]['urlToImage']}}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:348px; height:233px; overflow:hidden; object-fit:cover;">
              </a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" style="height:116px;">{{rtn[1]['title']}}</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{rtn[1]['url']}}">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{{rtn[2]['urlToImage']}}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:348px; height:233px; overflow:hidden; object-fit: cover;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" style="height:116px;">{{rtn[2]['title']}}</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{rtn[2]['url']}}">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `*ngFor` to iterage the rtn elements? You use the same HTML for each element

```
<div class="carousel-item active">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let element of rtn">
    <div class="card mb-2">
      <a href="{{element['url']}}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{element['urlToImage']}}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:348px; height:233px; overflow:hidden; object-fit:cover;">
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title" style="height:116px;">{{element['title']}}</h4>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{element['url']}}">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Also, did you check in your css if you have something like `.row a.btn { pointer-events: none; }`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The Carousel had indicators that I didn't show in my code above.  These indicators were blocking the anchor buttons from being clicked, so I set them to {pointer-events: none} in the CSS.  Thanks for the help.